# Show the following upper bound without evaluating the integral.

Tags: complex-analysis, upper-lower-bounds, line-integrals

Let C be a contour consisting of line segment from $-4$ to $0$ followed by the line segment from $0$ to $3i$. Without evaluating the integral, show that$$\bigg|\int_C(e^z-\bar{z})\, dz\bigg|\leq 28+4e^{-4}.$$

I started with
$$\bigg|\int_C(e^z-\bar{z})\, dz\bigg|\leq\int_{z=-4}^0|e^z-\bar{z}|\, |dz|+\int_{z=0}^{3i} |e^z-\bar{z}|\, |dz|$$ $$\leq\int_{z=-4}^0|e^z|\, |dz|+\int_{z=-4}^0|\bar{z}|\, |dz|+\int_{z=0}^{3i} |e^z|\, |dz|+\int_{z=0}^{3i}|\bar{z}|\, |dz|$$
Please help how to go ahead.

Comment: Technically your inequalities are incorrect because they are still complex numbers. You need $|dz|$ too.

Comment: Ok. I am editing the question.